# Rails 4 SQLite bug? Numeric (integer, float, decimal) 0 gets passed as nil on 'update'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I've encountered what seems to me to be some strange behaviour in Rails 4 with SQLite.

Whenever I attempt to store a zero in a numeric (integer, float, decimal) column:

- `update_columns( my_column: 0 )` stores a `0` in the db as expected
- `update( my_column: 0 )` stores a `nil` in the db, which is not what I expected

This is true whether passing a number (`0` or `0.0`) or a string (`'0'` or `'0.0'`) in all cases, and with validations disabled for this column.

The SQL code echoed in the console confirms that Rails is generating `0` (or `0.0` or `'0'` or `'0.0'`) as the update value in the first case, and `nil` as the update value in the second.

Is this a bug in Rails?

Comment: It's time for me to switch this project to postgreSQL anyway...

Comment: Any chance you have a before filter (or attribute normalizer) in place?  update_columns does a direct SQL update and skips callbacks.  update doesn't.  Maybe you've got something in place that's turning 0 into nil similar to turning blank strings into nil?

Comment: I thought I had completely checked that possibility before posting this question, but buried deep I was turning 0 into nil -- leftover from debugging efforts a while back which I had forgotten about. And then I got stuck on the idea that it was a Rails bug.  `:-|`  So thanks for the nudge! Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you have a before filter (or attribute normalizer) in place? update_columns does a direct SQL update and skips callbacks. update doesn't. Maybe you've got something in place that's turning 0 into nil similar to turning blank strings into nil?